# Is the norm of the average $\le$ the norm of the max?

Tags: inequality, normed-spaces, average

Given $\pmb X \in \mathcal{R}^p$, denote the elements of $\pmb X$ as $\pmb x_i$ for $i= 1, \dots, n$.
Denote the $t(\pmb X)$ as the average of $\pmb X$
\begin{equation}
\pmb t(\pmb X) = \frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n \pmb x_i
\end{equation}

so, $\pmb t(\pmb X)$ is a vector and I can takes it Euclidean norm as $\|\pmb t(\pmb X)\|$. Further, denote $\pmb x_m$ where $m$ refers to the $m$th index, such that $\| \pmb x_m\| \ge \| \pmb x_i\|$ for any $i \ne m$. In other words, $\pmb x_m$ has the maximum norm of any element in $\pmb X$.

My question is this. Is it true that 
\begin{equation}
\|\pmb t(\pmb X)\| \le \|\pmb x_m\|\text{ ?}
\end{equation}
This seems obvious to me, but I would like to confirm that it is obvious enough to claim without a proof. If a proof is necessary, is Jensen's inequality a way to show this, and if so how (to my disgrace, clearly the fact that I am not sure indicates a proof is necessary at least for me)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By homogeneity and the [triangle inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29#Definition)
$$\left\|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nx_k \right\|=\frac{1}{n}\left\|\sum_{k=1}^nx_k \right\|  \leq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\|x_k \| \leq\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\|x_m \| =\|x_m\| $$

Comment: Here, when you write $|x_i|$ do you mean the absolute value of $|x_i|$ or the norm? Just checking, since I was using || for the norm and bold face for vectors.

Comment: It is not clear in the OP what is the norm... $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^n x_i$ is not a norm but a mean (it can be negative). To make it a norm you can add absolute values: $N(x)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^n|x_i|$, and then using the same proof you can observe $\min_{i} |x_i|\leq N(x) \leq \max_{i} |x_i|$. Note that $N(x) = \frac{1}{n}\|x\|_1, \|x\|_\infty =\max_i |x_i|$

Comment: What do you mean by $min \; x_i \le x_k$ since these are vectors? Do you mean the norm the $x_i$ is the smallest? I did not mean to imply that all elements of the vector $x_m$ are the largest for each variable. Just that $x_m$ has the largest norm. Vector inequalities as used above typically imply the inequally holds for all elements in the vectors, right? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_(mathematics)#Vector_inequalities

Comment: Thanks! That make a lot more sense to me. A last question. Why do you need $k = 0$? instead of $k = 1$?

Comment: Sorry first I misunderstood your question and then it was a typo.